# SQL Server: Split Data in a column based on a delimiter and then join with reference table to get ID values associated

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-synapse

I would like to achieve the column **Expected** in the screenshot below. Could you please help me achieve this on Synapse Datawarehouse using the following table scripts and sample data.

Note:

1. This is just a sample data set. The original Users table would have millions of rows.
2. **Users** column can more than **N** number of users separated with delimiter ';'

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE [BTS_Test].[Users]
(
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Users] [varchar](500) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
);

INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Users] VALUES('2023-01-11','Rupesh; Suresh; Yogesh');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Users] VALUES('2023-01-11','Anne; Prudvi; Mahesh');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Users] VALUES('2023-01-11','Bobby');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Users] VALUES('2023-01-11','Crystal; Abella');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Users] VALUES('2023-01-11','Balaji; Kishan; Silpa; Sindhu Srinivas; Kiran');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Users] VALUES('2023-01-12','Cindrella');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Users] VALUES('2023-01-12','Monika; Chandler');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Users] VALUES('2023-01-13','Niko Paul');

CREATE TABLE [BTS_Test].[Student]
(
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [StudentName] [varchar](500) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE
);

INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(1,'Rupesh');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(2,'Suresh');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(3,'Yogesh');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(4,'Anne');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(5,'Prudvi');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(6,'Mahesh');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(7,'Bobby');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(8,'Crystal');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(9,'Abella');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(10,'Balaji');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(11,'Kishan');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(12,'Silpa');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(13,'Sindhu Srinivas');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(14,'Kiran');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(15,'Cindrella');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(16,'Monika');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(17,'Chandler');
INSERT INTO [BTS_Test].[Student] VALUES(18,'Niko Paul');
```

Comment: Rather than creating another delimited string of IDs, why not take this opportunity to normalize your data ?

Comment: Hi John, This data is coming from source and the requirement is to have another column with ID's

Comment: Search for and review documentation and tutorials on `STRING_SPLIT()` and `STRING_AGG()`. You should find what you need there.

Comment: See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/m3FgALFl) for a general example that uses STRING_SPLIT() and STRING_AGG() to map a delimited list of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option using JSON to keep the sequence.  Performance over millions of rows???  ***Just keep in mind there are penalties for storing delimited data.***

**Example**

```
Select * 
 From [Users] A
 Cross Apply ( 
              Select Expected = string_agg(ID,';') WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY [key] )
               From  OpenJSON( '["'+replace(string_escape([Users],'json'),';','","')+'"]' )
               Join  [Student] on trim(Value)=StudentName
             ) B
```

**Results**

```
Date        Users                                           Expected
2023-01-11  Rupesh; Suresh; Yogesh                          1;2;3
2023-01-11  Anne; Prudvi; Mahesh                            4;5;6
2023-01-11  Bobby                                           7
2023-01-11  Crystal; Abella                                 8;9
2023-01-11  Balaji; Kishan; Silpa; Sindhu Srinivas; Kiran   10;11;12;13;14
2023-01-12  Cindrella                                       15
2023-01-12  Monika; Chandler                                16;17
2023-01-13  Niko Paul                                       18
```

Comment: Starting with SQL Server 2022, STRING_SPLIT() supports the enable_ordinal option, so it can now be reliably used to preserve value order.

Comment: @TN Yes I know.  That was a ridiculous omission on their part.  Just rolling the dice OP was not on 2022

Comment: On synapse, I get error -

Msg 104162, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'string_escape' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Answer (score 0):

This produces results using STRING_SPLIT and XML:

```
SELECT u.[DATE], u.USERS, (STUFF((SELECT ';' + Y
FROM (select CAST(s.id AS VARCHAR) AS y from STRING_SPLIT (u.USERS, ';') sp
INNER JOIN STUDENT s on s.STUDENTNAME = trim(sp.Value)) X
FOR XML PATH('')) ,1,1,'')) as EXPECTED
FROM USERS u
```